# C simple array code isn't working

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, if-statement

my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i, choice;
int player [11] = {1,    2,   10,   13,   21,  22,  24,   25, 31,32,   33};
int points [11] = {60, 297, 11, 373, 154, 52, 555, 218, 29, 242, 257};
int games [11] = {33, 35,  12,  35,   35,  35,  35,   35, 22,35,   35};
int assists [11] = {64 , 27 ,   2   ,  112  , 23 ,  3  ,   53 ,  39 ,  4 , 15 ,   9 };
int rebounds[11] = {30,134,3,122,85,43,210,58,17,211,169};
const char* names[11] = {
    "Jaylon Tate","Joe Bertrand","Jaylon Tate","Tracy Abrams","Malcolm Hill","Mav Morgan","Rayvonte Rice","Kendrick Nunn","Austin Colbert","Nnanna Egwu","Jon Ekey"
};
printf("Number\tGames\tPoints\tAssists\tRebounds\n");
int bestplayerppg = 0;
int bestplayerapg = 0;
int bestplayerrpg = 0;
float bestppg = 0.0;
float bestapg = 0.0;
float bestrpg = 0.0;
float ppg [11] ;
float apg [11];
float rpg [11];
int bestIndexppg = 0;
int bestIndexapg = 0;
int bestIndexrpg = 0;
for (i=0; i<11; i++){
    ppg[i] = (float)points [i] / (float)games [i] ;
    apg[i] = (float)assists [i] / (float)games [i] ;
    rpg[i] = (float)rebounds [i] / (float)games [i] ;
    printf("%s \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %.1f ppg \t %.1f apg \t %.1f rpg\n", names[i], games[i], points[i], assists[i], rebounds[i], ppg[i], apg[i], rpg[i]);
    if (ppg[i]>bestplayerppg){
        bestplayerppg = player[i];
        bestppg = ppg[i];
        bestIndexppg = i;
    }
     if (apg[i]>bestplayerapg){
        bestplayerapg = player[i];
        bestapg = apg[i];
        bestIndexapg = i;
    }
    if (rpg[i]>bestnorpg){
        bestplayerrpg = player[i];
        bestrpg = rpg[i];
        bestIndexrpg = i;
    }
}
printf("Pick the stat you want to view:\n1. Points per game\n2. Assists per game\n3. Rebounds per game\nEnter a choice: ");
scanf("%d",&choice);
printf("The player with the most ");
switch (choice){
    case 1:
    printf("points per game is #%d %s with %.1f ppg.\n", bestplayerppg, names[bestIndexppg], bestppg);
    break;
    case 2:
    printf("assists per game is #%d %s with %.1f apg.\n", bestplayerapg, names[bestIndexapg], bestapg);
    break;
    case 3:
    printf("rebounds per game is #%d %s with %.1f rpg.\n", bestplayerrpg, names[bestIndexrpg], bestrpg);
    break;
    default:
    printf("Choice is not valid\n");
} 
}
```

The code works perfectly for points and assists. But it doesn't work when finding the top rpg. It says #13 Tracy aka the fourth element in the array has the most rpg when he doesn't. My logic for points, assists, and rebounds is the same but only points and assists work...

Comment: The third if is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (rpg[i]>bestnorpg){
        bestplayerrpg = player[i];
        bestrpg = rpg[i];
        bestIndexrpg = i;
}
```

bestnorpg is not declared anywhere.

Try the following:

```
if (rpg[i]>bestrpg){
        bestplayerrpg = player[i];
        bestrpg = rpg[i];
        bestIndexrpg = i;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `bestrpg` suppossed to be `bestplayerrpg`?